# Rails: filtering in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm using rails and I have this models

```
Job
  has_many :job_fonctions
  has_many :fonctions, through: :job_fonctions

JobFonction 
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :fonction 

Fonction
    has_many :job_fonctions
    has_many :jobs, through: :job_fonctions
```

what I want is to sort all jobs that have the same fonction as the current job in the show page I have tried this code in my controller

```
@related_jobss = Job
    .where('jobs.id != ?', @job.id)
    .where(:fonction_id=>@job.fonction)
```

but this give me this error `undefined method`fonction' for`, so I'm wondering on how to do it?

This is my view code

```
<% @related_jobs.each do |job| %>
    <%= link_to truncate(job.job_title, length: 45, escape: false).html_safe, job%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Because it is a has_many relationship, the method call is `@job.fonctions` not `@job.fonction`, and it will return all of the fonctions related to @job (not a single id). Do you want to match all of @job's fonctions or just one? Also, the fonction_id should be in JobFonction, not Job, so once you know the fonction id/ids you are looking for, you would look them up in JobFonction to find the corresponding Jobs.

Comment: i want to match at least one fonction

Comment: Try in console: `@job.fonctions.first.jobs`. That should give you a list of all jobs associated with the first fonction associated with @job.

Answer (score 1):

You would have a better experience by creating a new class to take care of this logic.  Do something like this in your model directory or create a new service directory that you autoload.

```
#in controller, @fonction can be any Fonction object
@related_jobss = RelatedJobFinder.new(@job, @fonction).with_same_fonction


#this would be in it's own file related_job_finder.rb
class RelatedJobFinder

  def initialize(job, fonction)
    @job = job
    @fonction = fonction
  end

  def with_same_fonction
    remove_this_job_from(jobs)
  end

  private

  def jobs
    Fonction.find(@fonction.id).jobs
  end

  def remove_this_job_from(relation)
    relation.reject{|job| job.id == @job.id}
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
@related_jobss = 
Job.includes(:fonctions)
.where('jobs.id != ?', @job.id)
.where(fonctions: { id: @job.fonctions.pluck(:id) } )
```

This should give you all `Jobs` with fonctions where the job is not equal to `@job` and that has any fonctions (one, two or all) that are the same as `@job.fonctions`.

I just tested this method with a relationship in my app (I'm running Rails 4.1.6 FYI) and I pulled out items that had only partial matches with the total array of ids that I listed.

Comment: when i try this i get this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column jobs.fonctions does not exist
LINE 1: ...fonctions"."fonction_id" WHERE (jobs.id != 5) AND "jobs"."fo...

Comment: So what does `@job.fonctions` give you? All the jobs related fonctions?

Comment: the job has_many :fonctions, through: :job_fonctions so @job.fonctions must give all the fonction of a job

Comment: I know that's what it **must** give you, but I'm wondering if that's what you **actually get** when you execute `@job.fonctions` in the console.

Comment: I just updated the code in the answer, give that a shot.

Comment: this code work can you explain it please the only limitation is that will return only relted jobs that have all the fonctions and not at least one fonction